# Why wont my drop down menu code work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Drop down menu will not work ! for css I used the "display: none;" to hide the list but Im wondering if this is the most efficient way to perform a drop down menu? I used this concept from a codeacademy project.

Im sure there might be some code in here that may make you cringe but please take it easy on me, I'm an absolute rookie at programming! Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').fadeToggle(400);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
.container {
  max-width: 230px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #024F79;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}
ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <p>How do I ?</p>
      <ul>
        <li>View my Transcript</li>
        <li>View my Conformation Page</li>
        <li>Register for Courses</li>
        <li>Pay for Courses/Exams</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: "It does not work" is not a valid question.

Comment: You shouldn't do it like this because as soon as you stop hovering the `p` tag(to select a menu option) the menu will fade out.

Comment: @JK. how do you suggest I word this kind of question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).find('ul')` will look inside of the `p` element as a result of using `this` as the context. You could use `.next()`

```
$(this).next('ul').fadeToggle(400);
```

However, a better approach would be to restructure your html and wrap the whole `p` and `ul` with a `div` that has an id in order to facilitate the UI fading.

```
<div id="menu">
 <p>How do I ?</p>
 <ul>
  <li>View my Transcript</li>
  <li>View my Conformation Page</li>
  <li>Register for Courses</li>
  <li>Pay for Courses/Exams</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And then use your original code except target the #menu item

```
$('#menu').hover(function() {
 $(this).find('ul').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/r1ve21f4/)***

Comment: Your first comment helped me understand why `$(this).find('ul')` did not work. For the sake of practice, I edited that line to `$('ul').find('li')` but this code did not work as well. Why?

Comment: @Walt - The `li` elements may fade in, but the `ul` will still be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using JavaScript, you can use pure CSS solutions, unless you want to make some animation.